# Django order by combination of direct and related fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stock_quantity = models.IntegerField()


class Variation(models.Model):
    parent_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='variations')
    stock_quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

what I want to do is sort a queryset of Products by stock_quantity.

Now, I have two types of products:

- simple products, who have a stock_quantity directly attached to them
- variable products, who have a stock_quantity of None, but have Variations that point to them via the foreign key. In that case, the variations all have a stock_quantity

For variable products, I want the sum of all the variation stock quantities to be relevant for sorting.

How can I do that?

I do have some ideas about annotations and aggregates in my mind, but not sure how to fit this all together.

Answer (score 0):

```
Product.objects.alias(true_quantity=Case(When(stock_quantity__isnull=True, then=Sum("variation__stock_quantity")), default=F('stock_quantity')).order_by('true_quantity')
```

[alias()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#alias) allows for additionnal culomn inside your resultset such as related or calculated ones (`alias()` won't expose the value when manipulating rows with Python, use [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) if you want `true_quantity` to be returned).
[Case()/When()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) allows for conditionnal expression.

The above query should yield your result, please let me know if anything remains unclear